# jQuery: Queue created elements

Tags: jquery

I want to:

1. Load the page empty slider
2. After page with images is loaded (`$(window).load()` ?), I want to inject slides into the slider.

But here's the thing - I don't want slide to be injected until the previous slide is fully loaded (text + big background image). Any ideas how do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

you can give this plugin a try:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: This is the answer IF we're dealing with <img>'s - due to the media queries & some reasons, I have to use divs with `background-image`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(window).load()` you can use this: `$(function () {});`

to check if an image is really loaded you can use this nice plugin:
http://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded